# CRecordset returns Positioned request cannot be performed

Tags: mfc, crecordset

I'm getting this error

> Positioned request cannot be performed because no searchable columns
> were bound

when I do a simple update. For example.

```
m_SystemConfigSet->GetRecord();
m_SystemConfigSet->Edit();
m_SystemConfigSet->m_value = 0;
m_SystemConfigSet->Update();
```

I filter by setting='hidDefaultFacilityGroupNumber'

The table I use only has two columns one is a primary key.

example:

```
setting (PK) | value
color        | 1
shape        | 4
```

my do field exchange is

```
pFX->SetFieldType(CFieldExchange::outputColumn);
RFX_Text(pFX, _T("[setting]"), m_setting);
RFX_Long(pFX, _T("[value]"), m_value);
```

Seems this error is very uncommon and the best I can tell it means my bound columns are simply not searchable. I'm not sure what a search column is?

Answer (score 0):

So I needed to add a numeric primary key. I guess non-numeric causes issue.